# How to use a variable in a loop later on

Tags: java

Im not sure if this is possible and im very new so hopefully some of you can shed some light on this, i have a function that reads all the contents of a txt file then prints this out in a terminal window, however i want to be able to store the data of the text file in a variable so i can use it later on is this possible

heres the snip bit of code :

```
String mText; 
        while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
            System.out.println(mText); 
        }
```

becuase as i understand it once the loop finishes the contents of the variable mText in this case gets deleted ?

ok becuase in my code below, i am wanting to print out to a printer, the contents of that file but when i run it, i can display the contents of the file just fine but it never comes up with printer option box, i thought this would be the problem, it looks like it is something else in my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PrintText implements Printable {
    private static String mText;

    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //selects the file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = file.getName();
        //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        //Reads contents of file into terminal 
        //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
        // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String mText; 
        while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
            System.out.println(mText); 
        } 
        //fr.close(); 
    } 

    //private static final String mText = 
    //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine

    AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);


    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    static public void printer(String args[]) {
        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

This is the original code i have done, it prints out a pre typed in text in the program, i have tried to add the file reader in as above and now it does not work

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintText implements Printable {
   /** private static String mText;

    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //selects the file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = file.getName();
        //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        //Reads contents of file into terminal 
        //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
        // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
            System.out.println(mText);
            list.add(mText); 
        } 
        //fr.close(); 
    } 
*/
    private static final String mText = 
        "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine

    AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);

    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't.  It just has the last value you assigned to it.  It's just that the last value is `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol - variable mText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006348/cannot-find-symbol-variable-mtext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as i understand it once the loop finishes the contents of the variable
>   mText in this case gets deleted ?

If you are reading multiple lines from your text file, then all the previous writes are overridden by the following writes. So, your variable `mText` will only contain the last line read.

If you want all your lines read to be accessible after the loop ends, you can store those lines in some collection.

Ideally, you can create a `List<String>` in this situation, and store your data in it: -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
        System.out.println(mText);
        list.add(mText); 
}
```

Now outside the while loop, you can access your data from the list.

Comment: thank you i have just tried this but am getting this complier error : type java.awt.list does not take parameters

Comment: thank you also for your detailed description it has helped me understand:)

Comment: @user1924104.. It's `java.util.List`. You have imported the wrong interface.

Comment: Thank you for all yours help :)

Comment: @user1924104. You're welcome :) But I see lot of problems with your code, but everything is not possible to point out. But I'll point a few. First problem I see is, you have declared your `mText` as `static variable` in class, and also a local variable in `main`. I'm pretty sure that's unintentional. Also, you should declare all your class level variables at the top to avoid making your code confusing. Apart from that, you can first concentrate on getting correct output. And then gradually improving your code. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you :), i have got the correct output at the terminal, however it does not print anything, i get no errors or anything, it is as if this section of the code does not run, any ideas ?

Comment: Where are you calling your printer method? Also, you should declare your `AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);` as local variable in your `print` method. And remove the `String mText;` declaration from inside the `main` method. Let it be at class level as you are having.

Comment: Ok, i have removed the string mText from main and now i can not compile as i get an error :cannot find symbol - variable mText, i did have this code working before but that was just with a pre set piece of text in main since i have added the file reader part it does not work

Comment: @user1924104. Ok. Don't remove it. Just keep it just like before. But, move your AttributedString line to your print method. And you didn't answer all my questions from my previous comments. Please answer them first before moving further.

Comment: ok, i have moved AttributedString  below, this have now caused another error on compile: cannot find symbol variable mStyledText, edited above is the orignal working code, i am not calling a print method at all looking at it, where and how would i call this method

Comment: @user1924104.. Where did you move AttributedString? you should move it in the method where you are using it. Just make it local variable in `print` method. And about `printer`, I can't tell you where to call from, because I haven't studied your whole code. I would suggest you to go through some basic tutorial regarding `Scope` and `Lifetime` of a variable. Also, `Classes and Objects`. You would find the Oracle tutorial so much helpful. And if you are a beginner in Java, then I would advice you to start with small problems. Learn the basics first. Then move further with complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

No. The variable is defined in the scope of the method, so it's value is available anywhere in the method after it is declared and given a value.

However, the code as you have it may not have assigned a value to the variable because readline() may throw an IOException, so you won't be able to use the variable after this loop - you will get an "possibly unassigned variable" compile error. To fix this problem, initialize the variable when you declare it:

```
String mText = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all lines, you must store them e.g this way:

```
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    String mText;
    while ((mText = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
        System.out.println(mText);
        sb.append(mText).append('\n');
    }
    // now the whole content of the BufferedReader is stored in sb.
```